# Converting a python file into executable file

Tags: python, kivy, windows-installer, exe, pyinstaller

I build a simple bouncing ball game using python and kivy and the game is working properly without any errors. To add Gui I have used .kv file. Then I converted the Python file into an executable file using the [pyinstaller](https://pypi.org/project/PyInstaller/) module to convert the .py file I have used the statement `pyinstaller -F PingPong.py`
It has generated the .exe file but when I run the .exe file it just opens a black window and gets closed after few second.
Can anyone please tell me why is it behaving like this and how to convert the .py into .exe
Thank you!

Comment: Are there dependencies that have to be installed with the exe? You can find and use depends.exe to find out which binaries it is using as a dependency at run time.

Comment: There is only one .kv file for the graphics

Comment: On your local machine where it runs fine start doing iterative testing and removing files until running it breaks in a similar fashion.